# Definir height no boostrap

Tags: bootstrap

Olá

Como eu defino a altura de uma linha no Bootstrap 4 ?

Meu codigo:

```
 <div class="row doc-grid">
   <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-8</div>
   <div class="col-md-9">.col-md-4</div>
 </div>
```

Obrigado

Comment: Já tentou nos CSS .doc-grid {height: XXpx;}?

Comment: Não queria alterar o codigo original

Comment: Não, basta dar uma classe/id diferente ao elemento para não alterar as default do bootstrap, assim estiliza o elemento como quiser

Comment: Eu não achei o .doc-grid

Comment: doc-grig é a classe do seu elemento row, olhe para o html que colocou na pergunta, está lá

Comment: Achei e coloquei o height: 100%, mas não alterou nada, eu já criei uma div com height 100%, mas tambem não deu em nada.